# How to fix the 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' when trying to get the value from Excel and input into Class

Tags: java, testng

Below is my simple Selenium TestNG program to pull the last name, first name & DOB from the 2nd row of the excel sheet and display the same inside the @Test annotation with the help of data provider. Used @BeforeTest annotation to open the browser before @Test.

```
   @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void processExcel(String lastName, String firstName, String DOB) throws InterruptedException
    {

        System.out.println(lastName);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        int colCount = 3;
        int rowNum = 1;
        String sheetName = "Excel_Sheet";
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);

        Object[][] data= new Object[rowNum][colCount];

        for(int i = 1;i<colCount;i++)
        {

            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            cell = row.getCell(i);

            if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                data[rowNum][i]= cell.getStringCellValue();
            else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                data[rowNum][i]= String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                data[rowNum][i]= "";
            //data[rowNum][i]=excel.getCellData(sheetName,rowNum,i);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

but I am getting the below exception and believe its related to the using of Array in the Data provider, tried with different ideas but still its blocking me so appreciate any kind of help. Thank you

```
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.hie.HH_Regression.ADTA01_HH.getData(ADTA01_HH.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:924)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Removed the Selenium tags since this code doesn't use Selenium. You should add a tag for the Excel library you are using. The best thing you can do is to learn how to debug your own code. Find a tutorial or look at the docs for your IDE. Put a breakpoint early in the script and walk through it looking at variable values, especially `data`, and spot the problem. Then you will more likely know how to fix it. Doesn't the index of an array start at 0 and not 1?

Comment: Used all the Excel libraries and getting exception exactly in the below row and I need to start from the Index 1 not 0.
data[rowNum][i]= String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());